# curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: self signed cert ificate in certificate chain

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-10

I try to create laravel project by typing command "composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app".
but not success. it throws error like below
In CurlDownloader.php line 372:

curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: self signed cert
ificate in certificate chain

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [ [ []]]

How could I fix to reate laravel project?

I try to find solution on the internet over 7 days but still not ok to fix the problem.

Comment: I do not think you have a Laravel problem. Most likely you have an old or misconfigured CA certificate store or possibly a misconfigured `php.ini` file - review the setting for `curl.cainfo`. See if this [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/curl-ssl-certificate-problem/) helps.